# iphone scroll down page with horizontal scrolling element

Tags: html, css, iphone, scroll

I have a page that has a horizontal scrolling element (a row of images that you can scroll sideways), its pretty simple.
My problem is that on an iPhone if I try to scroll the page vertically and I scroll starting from the area of the horizontal scrolling element, the page doesn't scroll.

On Android devices it works fine, Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix this?

**UPDATE:**
I found the culprit my themes css has the following `html,body {height: 100%;}`, I am still interested in understanding why it causes this and how i can fix it without removing that line, (I did not design the theme and can't be sure that css isn't necessary)

```css
div {min-height: 2000px}
ul {white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;}
li {display: inline-block; margin: 5px; background: #555;}
html,body {height: 100%;}
```

```html
<div>
stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br>
<ul><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li><li>side sliding elemntts</li></ul>
stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br> stuff<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the `html` and `body` style for `height` are not set

Comment: see my comment above